# Flutter Visibility widget takes empty place

Tags: flutter, dart

When I tried to hide a widget using visibility, the hidden widget took an empty place like attached screenshot. how to fix this?

[src gist](https://gist.github.com/gokulsundar188/1395d654a7c79946c2b80b1187c554fb)

[image]

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I attached gist link above screenshot @JayDangar

Comment: it's not well formatted and hard to look at, kindly format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SizedBox flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html), whenever you want to show a null/empty item for hiding the the item

```
// Without visibility you can use
_dynamicListMenu[index].name == "profile" ? Your_widget_to_show : SizedBox()
```

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use SizedBox.shrink instead of plain SizedBox.

```
_dynamicListMenu[index].name == "profile" ? Your_widget_to_show : SizedBox.shrink()
```

as stated [here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)

Comment: even returning container() with no child elements would work too.

Comment: no, it's not worked got the same output.

Comment: post your whole code with formatting. I

Comment: yes, I'll post the code, I actually wrapped this widget with GridView,  GridView's childAspectRatio assumes widget is still there even though it's hidden.

Comment: I got the output but replacing GridView with ListView.

Comment: good for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Visibility widget wrapped with GridView, GridView's childAspectRatio assumes widget is still there even though it's hidden. so GridView replaced by ListView now the issue has Fixed.

[src gist](https://gist.github.com/gokulsundar188/22aaf37e450d6c93702f5afd37fd42eb)

[image]